# Reference Serializer fields from Model in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

The usual way of creating ModelSerializer in `Django Rest Framework` is specifying the fields attribute:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelConfig
        fields = (
            'id', 'uid', 'hashid', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'added_by', 'updated_by', 'qr_code',)
```

However in bigger projects, refactoring can be easier if the fields can be referenced through their Model, instead of specifying them as a string literal. However I don't know how this could be done in the most OOP way.

I have tried using `Model._meta.get_field(field)` but this also only accepts the `field_name`, not a reference to the attribute.

Something like `Model.field.name` would be great.

Is this somehow possible?